# How to past together redirect 301 rewrite iis-8.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

i faced a problem. There is a main domaim https://example.com i have a redirect from http to https. everything works, but there is a problem, when i try to print in the url adress request line www.example.com/exam/exam i am redirected to the maim page and in the adress request line i see the following adress : https//example.com and other requests are deleted.But if I enter into the address bar https://example.com/exam/exam - 
then everything works. I need your help and advise on how can i improve rewrite and what is wrong in my code?

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([\d\w\.]+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectDoubleHTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your second rule. It should be like that:

```
<rule name="RedirectDoubleHTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

Also your first rule have minor fix. Instead `https://{C:1}/{REQUEST_URI}"` should be `https://{C:1}{REQUEST_URI}"`